# Changing default Mosquitto MQTT Port on PHP server

Tags: php, android, port, mqtt

I am running a MQTT server on PHP and using Android to connect to it. The problem I faced is that I am unable to get the default port 1883 opened for MQTT due to server restrictions. Only common ports (21, 80, 3306, 8080) are opened. Is there any 'hack' that will allow me to use these ports for my MQTT? I have tried ports 80, 3306 and 8080 but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, typically the ports above 1000 are privileged and restricted anyway. What is happening when you adjust the broker settings to start on a different port? are those ports you list already opened by other applications?

From the perspective of MQTT it will just be a case of setting the port number in the broker configuration and starting the broker. I can't see what else can help here?

Comment: I have tried, MQTT will have conflict with any ports that is already opened by other applications. Guess I have no choice then.

Comment: :-( yeah, well if those ports are already in use then it doesn't matter whether it is an MQTT broker or anything else, you can't reuse the port. Are you able to ask for another one to be opened on your server?